# Google Structured Data Testing - The value provided for image.url must be a valid URL

Tags: php, web, structured-data

Google structured data [tester](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) gives the following error for the `ImageObject` property.

`The value provided for image.url must be a valid URL.`

However, image URL exists and has no problem. Any idea?

Comment: Is the URL accessible publicly on the internet, or is it an internal/private/localhost address?

Comment: @MarkH. yes Mark, it is available publicly

Comment: Have you tried adding http and removing http delimiters in your Url? Some apps expect http, some do not

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error as well. I notice that Google structured data tester seems to have problems with image names containing .svg_ or .svg before the extension. e.g. 240px-Text-html_Gion.svg_.png or cloud.svg.jpg. When I truncate the image name to 240px-Text-html_Gion.png and use that image instead, it then works without error.